# Converting Azure "classic" storage accounts

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

I've created some [Azure Machine Learning](https://studio.azureml.net) Workspaces and associated them with "classic" storage accounts; but would like to have them associated with "not-classic" (or whatever the term is) storage accounts.

Is there a way to convert the storage accounts from "classic", or to change the storage account associated with a Machine Learning Workspace?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I assume "classic" is Newspeak for "old", no?

Comment: One reason would be to migrate a storage account to another subscription, at the moment you cannot migrate classic storage accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, there's no automatic way of converting a "Classic" storage account into "Azure Resource Manager (ARM)" storage account. Today, you would need to copy data from a classic storage account to a new storage account.

Having said that, there's no difference in how the data is stored in both kinds of storage accounts. Both of them support connecting via account name/key and/or shared access signature. The difference is how these storage account themselves are managed. In ARM storage accounts, you can assign granular role-based access control (RBAC) to control what a user can do as far as managing the storage accounts (like updating, deleting, viewing/regenerating keys).

Regarding your question about using new storage accounts with ML workspace, I don't think it's possible today (I may be wrong though). Reason being, ML is still managed via old portal which doesn't have the capability to manage ARM storage accounts.

Comment: There is difference. I have classic storage and CDN verizon cant see it

Answer (score 4):

After the question was asked and answered, Microsoft provided a way to achieve this through PowerShell. I have successfully used the steps in [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-ps-migration-classic-resource-manager) to convert Classic resources to the new ARM architecture, including Storage accounts (detailed near the bottom of the article).

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me on multiple classic storage accounts,.. if only migrating storage accounts skip past the VM migration steps to the bottom of the article.

Comment: That doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240150/migrating-or-using-old-vhd-on-a-classic-storage-account-to-be-used-with-new-n

Answer (score 1):

You can not convert classic to resource manager. The best way to move to rm is make a rm storage and copy the content from the old account.